# How to delete custom options value of a product programatically without deleting the option

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I want to delete custom options value of a product programatically without deleting the option.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way for do this:

This code will delete all options values but not the options.

```
$product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);

foreach ($product->getOptions() as $_option) {
        $values = $_option->getValues();
        foreach ($values as $v) {

                echo $v->getTitle();
                $v->delete();

            }
        }
    }
```